# Modifying PowerShell script to change the default Font type and size for Outlook

Tags: azure, powershell, outlook, exchange-server, intune

We're using Azure Intune on our environment and I'm trying to use a PowerShell command through Intune to change the default font for "New mail messages" and "Replying or forwarding messages" to Arial 11.

Is this something can be done through PowerShell?

We're using Outlook 365 so no on-permiss server/exchange and we use Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: you could use `Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration` with `[-DefaultFontName <String>]` and  `[-DefaultFontSize <Int32>]`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/client-access/Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ps

Answer (score 1):

As Matthew mentioned, you can use `Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration` PS command to do it.
I have tested on my side and it works for me:

[image]
[image]

Try the command below:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration <account you want to config> -DefaultFontName Arial  -DefaultFontSize 11
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58315862/6045800) by [Stanley Gong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10189459/stanley-gong) only works for Outlook Web App - In addition you can do this for all mailboxes with the following:

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName <yourUPN> -ShowProgress $true

$mailboxes=get-mailbox
$aliases=$mailboxes.alias
$number= ($aliases).count
foreach ($alias in $aliases)
    {
       set-MailboxMessageConfiguration -Identity $alias -defaultfontname 'Arial' -defaultfontsize 11
        
       #Inplace of Font 'Futura LT Book' you can replace with your own.
       #get-MailboxMessageConfiguration -Identity $alias | ft identity, defaultfontname
       #Check the validity of the configuration. Note: Disable Set while checking fonts
       
      write-host 'Font has been Configured for' $alias 
      
    }

Write-host 'Total changes made is' $number
```